# Specify a general scalar function within a vector operation in Mathematica?

Tags: function, vector, wolfram-mathematica, scalar

I am trying to take the derivative of a function that includes a scalar function of a vector and the vector itself. A simpler example of this is:

```
D[ A[b[t]]*b[t]/(b[t].b[t]), t]
```

where `b[t]` is a 3-vector and `A[b[t]]` is a scalar function. I get nonsense back out, since Mathematica isn't properly defining `A[b[t]]` to be a scalar.

I've tried using `$Assumptions = {(b[t]) \[Element] Vectors[3, Reals], (M[b[t]] | t) \[Element] Reals}` and this doesn't seem to help.

Any tips?

Edit to add more detail:

In that example case, I should get:

```
A/(b[t].b[t]) * (2(b[t].b'[t])b[t]/(b[t].b[t])^2 - b'[t]) 
- D[A,b]*1/(b[t].b[t])^(3/2) * (b[t].b'[t])b[t]
```

Where ' denotes a derivative with respect to t.

Mathematica gives everything correctly except the last term. The last term is instead:

```
-((b[t] b'[t] M'[b[t]])/b[t].b[t])
```

Comment: Hi, could you tell what your expected output should look like?

Comment: @mikuszefski Sure! I've edited the original question to include the expected output and the output Mathematica is giving me.

Comment: I guess you have to rewrite the `D` of Mathematica. You have to implement that, e.g.,`x.x` actually is `xT x` and then apply the according rules for the derivative of the transposed . A short discussion is given [here](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/861487). A detailed discussion on how to do that is probably for Mathematica-SE

Comment: Thank you, @mikuszefski! That seems like it would work. I ended up just doing my calculations by hand, but I'll keep this in mind for future work.

Comment: Right. This discussion might be helpful as well: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/138708/differentiating-functions-of-vectors-matrices